2018 Chevy Silverado's touchscreen malfunctioning
I have a 2018 Chevy Silverado. I bought it brand new 6 years ago and its been running great.
Suddenly, the touchscreen in the center dashboard started malfunctioning and its getting noticeably worse every few days. Every 10 - 20 seconds, a random onscreen button is selected and the screen changes. I have uploaded a video that shows whats happening.
What would cause this and what might the fix be?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

This seems to be a very common problem with these touchscreens. According to this video, it happens to most vehicles using this screen after about 4 to 6 years of usage. I also have a 2018 Silverado, but mine is still working fine, but after seeing this, I wonder how long it will be good until I'm in the same boat as you ;-)
One thing you can try before replacement is to reset the head unit. To do this:

Reboot the system: Put the vehicle in park, then press and hold the steering wheel's End Call button for about 15 seconds until the screen goes black. Release the button, and after 5–10 seconds, the welcome screen should appear and the infotainment system should reboot.

(Note: This was copied from AI input through Google.)
If that doesn't work, your only other option is replacement. While I have no affiliation with the company in the video, their option seems like the best/cheapest way to go. I haven't tried the dealership to see how much they'd charge, but would bet it's not going to be cheap. The instructions in the video seem easy enough any DIY'er should be able to accomplish.

Thanks @Paulster (I'd upvote your answer if I had the rep to do so!). I appreciate your suggestion to try to reboot the infotainment console, but I can verify that holding the End Call button down for even a full minute does nothing, at least in my truck. I will probably end up giving that company's touchscreen a try, and will post back with my results when I get to it. That probably won't be for another month or two, however!

In the meantime, I will probably tape some ugly cardboard over the screen since the constant UI changes are becoming distracting. But there is also the matter of the clicking noise that I hear whenever this "ghost"/"phantom" makes a UI selection. Any ideas where this noise is coming from, or how I can silence it? Its every few seconds and is becoming distracting and annoying on its own! Thanks again for any help!

I see this is an older thread, just want to add what I've experienced.
Twice I've had problems:the infotainment center, blower motor, controls on steering wheel, front blinker, one headlamp, park assist not working. First time, after much trial and error, I cleaned a specific connection and all was right with the truck. Second time, several months later, I went straight to that connection. Again, all was working right after. So, I believe it to be the culprit. Not exactly sure what it's called but under the very top battery cover there's blue connector the contacts appeared to have a little oxidation when I unplugged it. Cleaned as best as I could with a pipe cleaner and sandpaper, then sprayed some CRC and let it dry. Hope this helps someone. Chased things, talked to various techs and got nothing.
